# Python: Short way implementation

Tags: python

I've got a little question: At the moment, I do the following:

```
", ".join((item[0][i][1] for i in range(len(item[0]))))
```

How can I insert the additional statement `"if item[0][i][1] not in blockedList"`  ?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Don't use range-len. Your expression is much cleaner as `', '.join(x[1] for x in item[0] if x[1] not in blockedList)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add it in your list comprehension as:

```
", ".join(item[0][i][1] for i in range(len(item[0])) if item[0][i][1] not in blockedList)
```

#### Note

You can simplify your code as follows:

```
', '.join(i[1] for i in item[0] if i[1] not in blockedList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of joining a two-dimensional array/list.

```
blocked = [(0,0,0,1),(0,0,1,1),(0,1,0,1),(0,1,1,1),(1,0,0,1),(1,0,1,1),(1,1,1,1)]
data = [(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,1,1)]

print ':'.join([''.join(str(col) for col in row) for row in data if row not in blocked])
```

> 0000:0010

I have devised a simple grammar for recursive joining of lists/arrays. This is by no means the official grammar. Please see links to official below.

```
LIST = [FUNCTION(ATOM) for ATOM in LIST if CONDITION]
STR = 'DELIM'.join(LIST)
```

Now if you notice, you can now easily substitute a `LIST` into the `LIST` for the `STR` grammar.

---

Here are the official python grammar rules for parsing:

***Python 2 Grammar:*** https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html
***Python 3 Grammar:*** https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html